Paired Negative Binomial
I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it, let's see if someone inspires me. in advance, thank you.
There is a parameter called ARR (annualized relapse rate) that is calculated as:
Number of events that all patients in a record have in a given period / (Number of patients x Sum of all Follow-up Times of all patients).
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9226307/
This parameter follows a Negative Binomial.
Well, I have to calculate this parameter, in a period before starting a treatment, and after a follow-up, calculate it again, for the same patients, after starting a treatment. So we would get the ARR before treatment, and the ARR after treatment.
To compare 2 independent negative binomials, we could make the quotient, which follows a Snedecor F distribution, but in this case, they are not independent, so I don't know where to go.
I don't know if, you could consider that, with a large sample size, the ARR follows a Normal distribution, and then make a comparison using a Student's T test for paired data, I see it a little bit for that reason.
any ideas?

where does this claim come from :"the ratio of two independent NBs is Fisher"?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9226307/
